# Cloudfront files not updating

Tags: wordpress, amazon-cloudfront, w3-total-cache

On my wordpress website, I use W3 Total Cache Plugin to serve files from Cloudfront. 
The CDN type is set to Generic Mirror. 
I optimize my images with EWWWW Image Optimizing Plugin and all images on my Media directory are very well optimized. 
The problem I have is that Google page speed says images aren't optimized because the images served are from Cloudfront. Compare the two URLs:

This is 39kb from cloudfront
http://d3c9o2or2ehzw4.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Ipad.jpg

This is 19kb from My server 
http://www.overcheap.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Ipad.jpg

What can I do to make my optimized files get served by Cloudfront?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your server has build in module to serve optimize image on the fly, for example, in Apache they have all sorts of optimization module, like mod_deflate ... etc.

But CloudFront doesn't have those and basically it is just a CDN proxying your S3 bucket that solve your latency problem.  So CloudFront won't do any optimization for your images.  **All the optimization has to do on your side before uploading**.

How about try jpegtran type of tools to optimize your images and upload to S3 again, and see if it decrease the size ?   http://linux.die.net/man/1/jpegtran

**And regarding to the files not updating** --> if you need to upload the same file with the same name, I will suggest you to invalidate the cache first on AWS console.  Because it will serve the same content everytime ( that's why it is call CDN ).